# Script that checks if a url loads a html page and contains a specific word then run a local script

Tags: html, shell

I need a shell script to be executed automatically as root that checks if a url loads a html page and if that page contains a specific word then run a local script.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  How many different ways can you come up with of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. Here is such a script:

```
URL=http://example.com # your URL
WORD=foo # the word you're looking for
THENCMD="echo Hello, world!" # the command you want to run on success
ELSECMD="echo File not found" # the command you want to run on failure

if curl -fs -- "$URL" | grep -q -- "$WORD"
then
    $THENCMD
else
    $ELSECMD
fi
```

Add  this file to your `/etc/crontab` to have it run at fixed time.

Comment: I am getting theses alerts:usage: mktemp [-d] [-q] [-t prefix] [-u] template ...
       mktemp [-d] [-q] [-u] -t prefix 
./check_url_word.sh: line 6: $FILE: ambiguous redirect
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file

Comment: @macweb What shell are you using? What OS are you on?

Comment: I am using MacOs 10.7.5 Terminal with the default login shell /usr/bin/login

Comment: @macweb Replace $(mktemp) with $(mktemp temp.XXXXXX) and try again.

Comment: I get this output:  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     4  100     4    0     0      3      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    13
test

Comment: the URL is pointing for a html file witch output "test". I don´t get the "echo Hello, world!".

Comment: Sorry I was teste the arrows and make a negative vote by mistake.

Comment: @macweb No problem. I've rewritten and simplified the script. Can you try the new script and see if it works for you?

Comment: I already try to click in triangle to set "This answer is useful" but it says that I need to have 15 reputation.Where is the grey tick mark ?

Comment: Right under the triangle-shaped buttons. It might appear only when you hover over the space where it should be.

Comment: ok I think tick in the right place.

Comment: Is there an possibility to add a "if then else" for ex: if $WORD then CMD1 else CMD2 ? this will improve a lot Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I can´t see any update.

Comment: @macweb Sorry, Stackoverflow must have eaten it up. Do you see the update now?

Comment: Just a little update how can we execute two commands in Then or Else ?Thanks

Comment: @macweb Just put two commands in there, each on its own line. You don't need to use $THENCMD or $ELSECMD.